# Erlang - Conditionally Omit A Property From A Couch DB View

Tags: syntax, mapreduce, erlang, couchdb, conditional-statements

I have an Erlang Couch DB that presents a JSON object like so:

```
fun({Doc}) ->
    Name = couch_util:get_value(<<\"name\">>, Doc),
    Value = couch_util:get_value(<<\"Value\">>, Doc),
    Geocode = couch_util:get_value(<<\"geocode\">>, Doc),
    Emit(
        Name,
        {[
            { <<\"value\">>,Value }, 
            { <<\"geocode\">>, Geocode }            
        ]}
    )
end.
```

The problem is that all the documents in this view do not have a 'geocode' property. In the case where a geocode is not present, I would prefer to not show it. In pseudo code, I would essentially like to to this...

```
Emit(
    Name,
    {[
        { <<\"value\">>,Value }, 
        Geocode != undefined ? { <<\"geocode\">>, Geocode } : null  
    ]}
);
```

I suspect it won't be as easy to do this in Erlang?

So far, my best solution is to:

```
fun({Doc}) ->
    Name = couch_util:get_value(<<\"name\">>, Doc),
    Value = couch_util:get_value(<<\"Value\">>, Doc),
    Geocode = couch_util:get_value(<<\"geocode\">>, Doc),
    % I think 'couch_util:get_value' returns the atom undefined, if the value doesn't exist.
    Undefined = undefined,
    if Geocode /= Undefined ->
        Emit(
            Name,
            {[
                { <<\"value\">>, Value }, 
                { <<\"geocode\">>, Geocode }            
            ]}
        );
    true -> Emit(Name, {[ { <<\"value\">>, Value } ]})
    end;
end.
```

Pretty sure there will be one or two syntax errors in there... please feel free to point them out!
But more importantly, is there a more efficient way to conditionally remove the 'geocode' value from the proplist / view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are trying to do is to filter out missing properties.

Let's genererate proplist with [list comprehension](http://www.erlang.org/doc/programming_examples/list_comprehensions.html):

`ListOfKeys = [<<"value">>, <<"geocode">>],
Proplist = [{Key, couch_util:get_value(Key, Doc)} || Key <- ListOfKeys],`

and let's [filter/2](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/lists.html#filter-2) out props with `undefined` value:

`FilteredProplist = lists:filter(
    fun 
        ({_Key, undefined}) -> false; % it matches => it's out
        ({_Key, _Value}) -> true
    end, 
    Proplist),`

Now you can just `Emit(Name, FilteredProplist)`.

It's also possible filter them out in list comprehension but it doesn't look clear:

`FilteredProplist = 
    [{Key, Value} || 
        Key <- ListOfKeys, 
        Value <- [couch_util:get_value(Key, Doc)], 
        Value /= undefined]`

EDIT:
Oh... I think i missed the most important question: How to write it in erlang?

`{[
        { <<\"value\">>,Value }, 
        Geocode != undefined ? { <<\"geocode\">>, Geocode } : null
]}`

the answer is:

`{
    [{ <<"value">>,Value }] ++ 
    if Geocode /= undefined -> [{ <<"geocode">>, Geocode }]; true -> [] end
}`